# how to show that product of two $C^s$ functions is $C^s\,$?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

> how to show that product of two $C^s$ functions is $C^s\,$?

i missed some mathematics due to Corona sickness and i am trying to work everything out. Problem is, that the worksheets are still going ahead and i am stuck at this proof. I dont know how to solve this until tomorrow. I would be realy grateful for any help.

[image]

Comment: image is in german. better to translate to english.

Comment: Of course, sorry. It says what i wrote in my question and the information that Omega and Theta are open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a point $c$, $f(x)=f(c)+(x-c) f_{1}(x)$ and $g(x)=g(c)+(x-c) g_{1}(x)$

This implies that
$$(f g)(x)=(f g)(c)+(x-c) r(x)$$

with $r(x)=f(c) g_{1}(x)+f_{1}(x) g(c)+(x-c) f_{1}(x) g_{1}(x)$. You can then see that $r$ is continuous at $c$, therefore, $f g$ is differentiable at $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. In the end it was just using the definition of a function beeing continious and simple calculating.... I wish you a nice evening.

Comment: @MarvinPelz I'm glad you got it, this way just implicitly uses first order Taylor, your approach would be better if you were asked to do it from first principles.